# $df_p$ not surjective

Tags: differential-geometry

From Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces By Docarmo.

DEFINITION 2. Given a differentiable map $F: U \subset R^n \to R^m$ defined in 
an open set U of $R^n$ we say that $p \in U$ is a critical point of F if the differential 
$dF_p: R^n \to R^m$ is not a surjective (or onto) mapping. The image $F(p) \in R ^m$ 
of a critical point is called a critical value of $F$. A point of $R^m$ which is not a 
critical value is called a regular value of $F$.

The terminology is evidently motivated by the particular case in which 
$F: U \subset R  \to R $ is a real-valued function of a real variable. A point $x_o \in U$
is critical if $f'(x_o ) = 0$, that is, if the differential $df_{x_o}$ carries all the vectors in 
R to the zero vector . Notice that any point $a \not\in f(U)$ is trivially a 
regular value of $f$.

If $f: U \subset R^3  \to R $ is a differentiable function, then $df_p$ applied to the 
vector $(1, 0, 0)$ is obtained by calculating the tangent vector at $f(p)$ to the 
curve $x \to f(x,y_o,z_o)$

It follows that

$df_p(1,0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_o,y_o,z_o)=f_x$

and analogousaly that 
$df_p(0,1,0)=f_y$,and $df_p(0,0,1)=f_z$

We conclude that the matrix of $df_p$ in the basis $(1,0,0), (0, 1,0), (0, 0, 1)$ is 
given by  $df_p=(f_x,f_y,f_z)$.

Note, in this case, that to say that $df_p$ is not surjective is equivalent to 
saying that $f_x = f_y = f_z = 0$ at p. Hence, $a\in f(U)$ is a regular value of 
$f: U \subset R^3 \to R$ if and only if $f_x,f_y$, and $f_z$ do not vanish simultaneously at 
any point in the inverse image
 $f^{-1}(a)$ = {$(x,y, z) \in U: f(x,y, z) = a$}.

In last pharagraph they have written  "$df_p$ is not surjective is equivalent to 
saying that $f_x = f_y = f_z = 0$ at p".

My question is Why $df_p$ is not surjective is equivalent to 
saying that $f_x = f_y = f_z = 0$ at p.Can someone explain me.Thanks in advance!

Comment: "$df_p = (f_x,f_y,f_z)$" should be interpreted as "$df_p$ is the linear map whose matrix with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is given by the matrix $(f_x,f_y,f_z)$". Since $\dim \mathbb{R} = 1$, every linear map to $\mathbb{R}$ is either surjective or identically $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$df_p$ is represented by the $1 \times 3$-matrix $(f_x,f_y,f_z)$. In order that $df_p$ be surjective the rank of this matrix at $p$ must be $1$. This is equivalent to $(f_x,f_y,f_z) \ne (0,0,0)$ in $p$.